# How to define a stateful DAG with user interaction in Airflow

Tags: airflow

I just started up Airflow for the first time and trying to figure out if it allows to run a "pipeline" with filters where a filter can be eitehr a shell task, or a micro service.

Consider the following scenario:

- Consider a web portal with registered users
- Users of this portal are able to start workflows "W1" and "W2". This also means that workflows need to run isolated between users, and they require state persistence.
- Let's assume workflow W1 is fully automated (and I'm not going to detail it). So it's a normal task which can be started and just finishes at some point.
- Workflow W2 however needs user interaction at some points in the workflow. Let's say workflow W2 comprises three steps:

  1) Preprocess data

  2) Expose the data via REST API, and allow (the user owning the workflow) to change the data. This can be a loop, so the user may change data multiple times until the workflow continues to the next step.

  3) Postprocess data

I have thus far three questions which I cannot figure via documentation or examples:

Q1: How can I define a DAG in Airflow for starting such workflow w2 in isolation per user?

Q2: How to "pause and continue" execution while hanging in the loop waiting for user interaction?

Q3: How to persist the workflow so it will never time out and can be continued at any time?

Small code example welcome (I'm also new to Python)!